# When parsing a space delimitated string, is there any advantage using getline over stringstream::operator>>?

Tags: c++, parsing, operators, getline, stringstream

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "my name is joe";
    std::stringstream ss{s};
    std::string temp;
    while(std::getline(ss, temp, ' '))
    {
        cout << temp.size() << " " << temp << endl;
    }

    //----------------------------//

    ss = std::stringstream{s};
    while(ss >> temp)
    {
        cout << temp.size() << " " << temp << endl;
    }

}
```

I've always used the former, but I'm wondering if there's any advantage to using the latter? I've typically always used the former because I feel that if someone were to instead change the string to a comma delimitated string, then all I need to do is put in a new delimiter, whereas the `operator>>` would read in the commas. But for space delimitation, it seems there is no difference.

Comment: I don't know about efficient, if you want to know that write a benchmark using quick-bench, but `while(ss >> temp)`  is the idiomatic way to read a space delimited string.  It also offers the flexibility to read any white space separated string and removes all leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline()` and `operator>>` are intended for different purposes. It is not a matter of which one is more advantageous than the other.  Use the one that is better suited for the task at hand.

`operator>>` is for [**formatted** input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction). It reads in and parses many different data types, including strings. If there is no error state on the input stream, it skips leading whitespace (unless the `skipws` flag on the input stream is disabled, such as with the `std::noskipws` manipulator), and then it reads and parses characters until it encounters whitespace, a character that does not belong to the data type being parsed, or the end of the stream.

`std::getline()` is for [**unformatted** input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction) of strings only. If there is no error state on the input stream, it does not skip leading whitespace, and then it reads characters until it encounters the specified delimiter (or `'\n'` if not specified), or the end of the stream.